# How to run sarge command in different directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have to run a command that only works in the directory where its .exe is located.

For example:

`...\rclone-v1.54.0-windows-amd64\rclone.exe`

How do you pass a directory as an argument on where to run sarge command

`...\rclone-v1.54.0-windows-amd64\`

```
from sarge import run
run('echo "Hello, world!"', cwd="...\rclone-v1.54.0-windows-amd64\")
```

Comment: `..` instead of `...`?

Comment: `...` is path to directory